# Wordpress MSSQL Installation

Tags: php, sql-server, wordpress

I have read all over the place how WordPress is only capable of working on MySQL, which I have no problem with, however where I work we are on MSSQL, and MSSQL alone.

I read here:
http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/10918

That there was at one point some stuff added to the code to potentially allow MSSQL functionality, I tried to work through some of the changes from that ticket, but got a little confused on some things.

Has there been any progress in making MSSQL available in the production code?

If not, what is the best way to implement the code from the ticket I listed above?

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JCreamer898** Hi, I tried looking for Wordpress and MSSql and here are some of the interesting things happening at their end and you might like it though I see it is a long way from there as of now...

http://wordpress.org/extend/ideas/topic/add-microsoft-sql-support

I think this is what you are trying to find...

:) I know, We both are looking in this direction see... Wordpress or Umbraco or Kentico Question still remains the same. does it not? if not... I hope I am on the same page with you.

cheers
**Prominerva**

Comment: Yea I saw that same post...Oh well, I guess I need to learn PHP better now and help get it done!

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in [Project Nami](https://github.com/ProjectNami/projectnami). It's not a plugin, but rather a fork of WordPress to run natively on MSSQL. It's specifically intended to take advantage of SQL Azure, but it's compatible with MSSQL Server 2012, as well.