# Wordpress with SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, wordpress

I was wondering if there is any way wordpress (php) can be used to write to a SQL Server . Simpler the better. We are currently looking at transferring our website over a CMS (preferrably wordpress) but we have all SQL Server databases.

Thanks for the insight guys.

Comment: Check this out: Wordpress/MSSQL Installation - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629048/wordpress-mssql-installation

Answer (score 3):

This is actually quite simple with the WP Db Abstraction plugin. I have been using it for months and it seems quite solid. After you extract the WordPress archive but before running the installer you will need to edit your wp-config.php file your database connection details. From that point it is just like running WordPress with MySQL. Fire up the browser and the installer will complete the setup of WordPress

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-database-abstraction/

P.S. This works great with SQL Azure as well

Answer (score 1):

You will want to be careful when following the Running WordPress on SQL Server tutorial mentioned by Remus Rusanu. It relies in a pre-built version of WordPress that is not up to date with the latest releases. It is safer to use the WP Db Abstraction plugin directly from the WordPress.org site.

Answer (score 0):

You may start looking at http://code.google.com/p/wordpress-mssql/.

My advice is to try a different approach that will avoid wordpress hacks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a detailed step by step how-to at [Running WordPress on SQL Server](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/archive/2010/05/12/running-wordpress-on-sql-server.aspx). It allows you to run on both standalone SQL Server or on a SQL Azure database.

Comment: This link isn't valid. Oops, 404 Error! That page can’t be found.

Comment: Internet Archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20190126235809/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brian_swan/2010/05/12/running-wordpress-on-sql-server/